# Different game objects with their respective collider that comes with different score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Game Manager script with a Ball Class attached in it that consists of different information of balls and another script that attached to the ball (game object) to detect collision. (Two scripts in total) So when the player collides with the balls, their respective scores will be counted.

```
public string[] ballColor; 
public int[] score;
```

Assume there are three balls at the beginning and here are the inputs:

1. Green Ball - 2 pts
2. Red Ball - 3 pts
3. Yellow Ball - 5 pts

Here is the collision script attached to the game object:

```
public void Start()
    {
        GameObject gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager");
        GameManager Ball = gameManager.GetComponent<GameManager>();

        ball_color = Ball.ballColor[count];
        ball_score = Ball.score[count];
    }
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

      

            if (ball_color.Contains(gameObject.tag))
            {
                //Debug.Log("Yes");
                score = ball_score;
                GameManager.instance.PlayerScore += score;
                Destroy(gameObject);
                count = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //Debug.Log("No");
                count++;
        }
    }
```

Game Manager script:

```
private int playerScore;
public string[] animalName;
public int[] animalScore;

public int PlayerScore
    {
         get
         {
             return playerScore;
         }
    
         set
         {
              playerScore = value;
              scoreText.SetText("Score: " + playerScore);
           }
     }
```

I realize there is a communication problem between these two scripts.

1. The game manager script is only passing the first value in the string array to the collision script and not updating afterwards, which means the point is always stuck on the first one.
2. The same goes for the `ball_color` information, only the first value in the string array is passed to the collision script and not updating afterwards, which means the color is always stuck on the first one.

As I would like to keep changing the points and colors of the balls whenever I want in the Unity editor without entering the visual studio afterwards.

How do I make the collision script gets the correct points of their respective balls without attaching individual scoring script onto each single game object and also without repeating the same `if(gameobject.tag == "Green")` comparison?

Comment: can you also show the game manager's script?

Comment: The game manager script is only passing the first value in the sting array, because u are not updating the arrays. The Start() function only runs once when u start the scene.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have added the game manager script. @IllegalRazer

Comment: Thank you! I get what you mean now, but I am struggling between choosing coroutine or update method, which one is considered less CPU processing...

Comment: I'll advide a coroutine for readability before you clog up your update method, but if you use an infinite while loop in your coroutine, it will be bad for your cpu. Maybe like wait a few ms between each update in the coroutine